# Rebuilding autocomplete index after having erased a repository in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I'm trying to rebuild the autocomplete index after having updated a repository in GraphDB.

I deleted all statements with the REST API (not the repo, just its content):

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:7200/repositories/my_repo/statements
```

And then I reloaded other statements from a file in a similar fashion:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-turtle" \\
-T my_file.ttl http://localhost:7200/repositories/my_repo/statements
```

After that, I rebuilt the autocomplete index through the workbench.

It seemed the right way, but it didn't work. For example, if I go in the visual graph section, also old items are proposed in the drop-down list as valid options, even if they are not present anymore. It's kind of like old entries are still present in the index. How can I align the index to current items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to rebuild the autocomplete index is to delete its folder, located in /data/repositories/your_repo/storage/autocomplete. The next time you initiate GraphDB you will need to enable again autocomplete.

Comment: Great! I guess there is no way to do that from the workbench, right?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: 6 years on, do you know if there is any way of "rebuilding" the autocomplete index using a API call or with a SPARQL query?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to rebuild the index in the WB. The same could be achieved with a POST request to http://localhost:7200/rest/autocomplete/reindex.